# Bouncy marker in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In Google Maps API v2 we can set to marker an option `bouncy:true`. It adds to marker eye-candy ability - after dragging this marker, it is bouncing.

Is it possible to do in API v3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a quick look at the API v3 spec for Markers - it doesn't look like the 'bouncy' option is available right now but I wouldn't be surprised to see this get implemented into the v3 API at some point - it's still in Beta and bound to change quite a bit.

- [Here is a link to the API v3 Reference on the available Marker Options](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MarkerOptions)

If you really wanted the behavior in a V3 Map now you could tie an event to the 'dragend' method on the Marker Object.  Have the function called alter the anchor point of the MarkerImage object - check out the MarkerImage object in the API too.

Comment: First thing I made before I wrote this post was reading this API Ref. ;)

Your idea is nice. In fact this bahaviour is not worth time which I should spend on writing this in current project but it is good to know this way of solution. ;)

Comment: This bouncy animation is available now.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Animation

Comment: Ah yup I just had a look at the changeLog - looks like Google Added the animation feature to the API on December 5th, 2010 - that should be the preferred approach for making a bounce animation.

Answer (score 15):

**Here's how you do it in V3**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(){

   marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was looking for a way for implementing bouncy markers in V3 of google maps so that if we are showing a cluster of markers, the currently selected marker should be visible clearly.

We used the z-index property of the marker to set the z-index of the current marker at a relatively higher value than the rest.