# How to set Google map marker bouncing?

Tags: javascript

Hi i need Google location marker bouncing when mouse over ,like
http://www.snapdeal.com/deals-bangalore_koramangala_plus
 .This link if click any location marker will bouncing,if anybody know let me know...

Comment: Duplicate of [Bouncy marker in Google Maps v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847616/bouncy-marker-in-google-maps-v3)

Answer (score 0):

```
GEvent.addListener(this, "mouseover", function() {
   var ToPixel = new GPoint();
   var AddOffset = new GPoint();
   var ToLatlag = new GLatLng();
   var currentProjection = G_NORMAL_MAP.getProjection();
   ToPixel = currentProjection.fromLatLngToPixel(**this.latlng**, this.map.getZoom());
   AddOffset = new GPoint(ToPixel.x,ToPixel.y-2);
   ToLatlag = currentProjection.fromPixelToLatLng(AddOffset,this.map.getZoom());
   this.setLatLng(ToLatlag);
   this.redraw(true);
}); 

GEvent.addListener(this, "mouseout", function() {
   this.setLatLng(this.latlng);
});
```