# Animate map Marker in GoogleMaps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create a custom marker that looks like that:

[image]

I have the drawable in XML that looks like that:

```
<solid
    android:color="#0093e8"/>

<size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="120dp"/>
```

[image]

Is it possible to add a "Wave effect" to the marker and the waves to be fading out gradually (as in the picture)? Also, this animation should be constantly playing (without the need of the user to tap on the map marker) What should I do?

Comment: Refer here : http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/implement-bouncing-marker-for-google.html

Comment: @SaravInfern Hey, thanks!

Comment: @SaravInfern I don't think that the solution there us helpful in my case because it suggest "animating" the position of the marker.

Comment: is this what you are lookin'  for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127154/wave-animation-for-imageview-android

Comment: I think the best way to do with your problem is by using animation on marker, because by using animation, you can exhibit dynamic movement in a variety of different circumstances. Check this [Github](https://gist.github.com/imminent/9183e661536914c7ff58) and this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847616/bouncy-marker-in-google-maps-v3) for sample code and information to make marker bounce.

Comment: @KENdi Thank you for your suggestion. I will try if that will work.

Comment: @SaravInfern Hi! Thank you! The "Wave" effect is what I am looking for, yes. However, I don't think I can transfer this to my map marker

Comment: @KENdi After inspecting the code that will work for situations such as when the user taps on the marker - it will play this bounce animation. However, this is not the effect what I am looking. In my case, I want the marker's animation to be constantly playing without the need of the user to tap/click on the marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did something pretty similar but i used a GroundOverlay instead of a marker, first i defined my custom animation:

```
public class RadiusAnimation extends Animation {
    private GroundOverlay groundOverlay;

    public RadiusAnimation(GroundOverlay groundOverlay) {
        this.groundOverlay = groundOverlay;

    }
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        groundOverlay.setDimensions( (100 * interpolatedTime) );
        groundOverlay.setTransparency( interpolatedTime );

    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }
}
```

then i run animation on the groundOverlay, after onMapReady :

```
...
  groundOverlay = mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                    .image(image)
                    .position(new LatLng(lat, lng), 100));
  groundAnimation = new RadiusAnimation(groundOverlay);
  groundAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
  groundAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
  groundAnimation.setDuration(2000);
  mapView.startAnimation(groundAnimation); // MapView where i show my map
...
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Will try if that will work :)

Comment: I cannot apply the "startAnimation" method on my GoogleMap object. It seems to not have such

Comment: it's a on the MapView https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView not the GoogleMap if you are using SupportMapFragment you can also do `View mapView = mapFragment.getView();` and it should work too

Comment: Hey. Thanks that worked! I will try to alter your solution to fit exactly to my design requirements and include multiple overlays :)

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev Hi, would you mind sharing how you did this with multiple overlays?

Comment: This animation works but it does not scale as a marker scales. So, on lower zoom levels the animation is not visible at all.